# Android Studio - How to load HTML5 content from a local path using Webview?

Tags: android, html, webview, local-storage

In the official Android developer page theres this topic Building Web Apps in WebView
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

I would like to know how to proceed if the content would be loaded from a local html folder, stored on src folder

I could not find any code example or sample to download.

Im using android studio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call JavaScript inside WebView from Android activity.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html

It is very good!

### /assets/mypage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
<title>My HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>MyHTML</h1>
<p id="mytext">Hello!</p>
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
<input type="button" value="Open Dialog" onClick="openAndroidDialog()" />
<script language="javascript">
   function showAndroidToast(toast) {
       AndroidFunction.showToast(toast);
   }

   function openAndroidDialog() {
       AndroidFunction.openAndroidDialog();
   }

   function callFromActivity(msg){
 document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = msg;
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello"
   />
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/msg"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
 android:id="@+id/sendmsg"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Msg to JavaScript"
   />
<WebView
   android:id="@+id/mybrowser"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

### main code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidHTMLActivity extends Activity {

 WebView myBrowser;
 EditText Msg;
 Button btnSendMsg;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);

       final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
        = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
       myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");

       myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
       myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");

       Msg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
    btnSendMsg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendmsg);
    btnSendMsg.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String msgToSend = Msg.getText().toString();
    myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\""+msgToSend+"\")");

   }});

   }

 public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
  Context mContext;

     MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
         mContext = c;
     }

     public void showToast(String toast){
         Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     public void openAndroidDialog(){
      AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
      = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidHTMLActivity.this);
      myDialog.setTitle("DANGER!");
      myDialog.setMessage("You can do what you want!");
      myDialog.setPositiveButton("ON", null);
      myDialog.show();
     }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Stick the html files in the assets folder, created (or found) in the root of the project

Access them with loadUrl():

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.htm");
```

where `index.htm` is the name of the file.

Comment: Thanks! The app would just have one main view loaded with the .html file, which consists of a HTML5 animation. Im using Android Studio default Android blank sample. Should I create another activity window or just goes with the default one ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android Studio and its project templates (waiting til it's stable to move over), but the default blank template  should be fine.

Comment: One thing though, if the html is using javascript from an external file, you will probably need to either put the js in the assets folder as well, and reference it in the html with no path, or use loadDataWithBaseURL() giving a base url for where the js file is, and converting the html into a String.